# What is the capacity of the memory for a Harvard Architecture system

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

<sub>**Harvard Architecture Image**</sub>
[image: Simple figure of Harvard Architecture]

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate the total memory capacity of both the program and data memory in a Harvard Architecture system.

In the image above, the **Opcode address** is labeled **"A<sub>0</sub> - A<sub>15</sub>"**. Does that mean there are only 16 addresses that would make the address 4 bits?

If so, does that mean the total memory address would be 16 x 16 (the remaining **Opcode bits**)?

Answer (score 4):

No A<sub>0</sub> - A<sub>15</sub> means that the address bus is composed of 16 lines (A<sub>0</sub>, A<sub>1</sub>… A<sub>15</sub>), then the address has 16 bits and can be comprised between 0 and 65535.